# locationManager(_:didUpdateLocations:) last entry is sometimes extremely outdated

Tags: ios, swift, location, cllocationmanager, cllocation

According to Apple's [own documentation around CLLocationManager](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/cllocationmanagerdelegate/1423615-locationmanager)

```
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation])
{
    locations.last // this is supposed to be the most recent 
}
```

However, during development, I sometimes notice that `locations.last` is sometimes minutes to hours out of date.

```
abs(locations.last.timestamp.timeIntervalSinceNow) // sometimes very large (e.g. 500, 5000, etc)
```

Does anyone have any ideas what might be causing this issue?

Comment: What is the issue exactly? Are you saying you sometimes get an array of locations where the last entry is not the most recent?  Or that you are surprised that the most recent known location is sometimes not very recent?

Comment: @Shadowrun. The latter. What would cause the most recent known location to be stale (when internet connectivity/permissions are all good)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When Location Service can't get the current location by requesting GPS server.

It will return the cached/recent location. That is why you see its timestamp is 1 min or 1 hour ago.

> It will return the cached/recent location.

This will help users to quickly access their current locations if they didn't travel significantly, that is when Accelerometer works to measure the movement of the device.